# OpenERP RML report with the non fixed size table

Tags: openerp-7

Please, i wannt to know how to realise in rml for openerp a report where in each page there is 5 columns.
Who can help me know 
Any suggestions 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is your second question on that same topic.
Dynamic columns are NOT possible unless you remove table and put into new one with more/less columns.

Further, I am not sure you understand what is column...

```
   row 0,0  |  column 0,1 |  column 0,2
   -------------------------------------
   row 1,0  |  column 1,1 |  column 1,2
   ...
```

So regarding that, there is no logical explanation to expand columns, only rows. Reason: You can't know how many columns there will be! Maybe you are sure that you have few dimensions, but in that case create few tables and test them!

Call function and if result is not by your liking:

```
removeParentNode('blockTable')
```

If that doesn't help I suggest that you consider changing table design...